# Sending a byte with .net UDP sockets in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sockets, udp

So i'm following a tutorial on how to setup a .net UDP Server and Client. So far it's going alright I can send a string to the server just like bellow.

```
byte[] send_buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello Server :)");
sending_socket.SendTo(send_buffer, sending_end_point);
```

However I ran into a slight issue. I want to send a byte instead of the string but I can't seem to work out how to do it. When I say byte I mean like an enum like bellow.

```
((byte)MyEnum.Enum1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to make sure that the underlying type for the enum you are casting is a byte. Otherwise you can run into problems.

If what you need is a byte array from your enum, use the following:

```
byte[] send_buffer = { ((byte)MyEnum.Enum1) };
```

Comment: Thank's Diego your a life saver!